# Ruby Binary Search Tree insert method stack level too deep

Tags: ruby, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a recursive insert method for a binary search tree but keep getting `stack level too deep` What is going on that it keeps giving me the error?

my node class

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :left, :right

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
    left = nil
    right = nil
  end
end
```

binary search tree class

```
class Bst
  attr_accessor :root, :size

  def initialize
    @root = nil
    @size = 0
  end

  def insert(value, root=nil)
    if @root == nil
      @root = Node.new(value)
    end
    if value < @root.value
      if @root.left == nil
        @root.left = Node.new(value)
      else
        return insert(value, @root.left)
      end
      return root
    end
    if value > @root.value
      if @root.right == nil
        @root.right = Node.new(value)
      else
        return insert(value, @root.right)
      end
    end
    return root
  end
```

It happens once I try to add 4 to the tree

```
tree = Bst.new
tree.insert(10)
tree.insert(6)
tree.insert(19)
tree.insert(4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you recurse and provide new `root`, you are still comparing the value with `@root.value`.

Since `4` is still less than `10`, you recurse, and pass `@root.left` as `root`. However, `root` is never used; you are again comparing `@root.value`, and recursing with `@root.left`, and those never change; thus, you have infinite recursion (or at least infinite till you blow the stack).

You want to be comparing to `root.value`, and recursing with `root.left` instead.

Having `@root` and `root` be different things is confusing, and leads to logic errors. Better variable naming would likely have prevented this error.

EDIT:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :left, :right

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
    @left = nil
    @right = nil
  end
end

class Bst
  attr_accessor :root, :size

  def initialize
    @root = nil
    @size = 0
  end

  def insert(value, node=nil)
    unless @root
      @root = Node.new(value)
      return
    end

    node ||= @root

    if value < node.value
      if node.left
        return insert(value, node.left)
      else
        node.left = Node.new(value)
      end
    elsif value > node.value
      if node.right
        return insert(value, node.right)
      else
        node.right = Node.new(value)
      end
    end
    @size += 1
    return node
  end
end

tree = Bst.new
tree.insert(10)
tree.insert(6)
tree.insert(19)
tree.insert(4)

p tree
```

Comment: I see what you're saying and I am trying to fix it in my code. I renamed root to node now and have in the arguement ```node=nil``` and have ```node = @root if @root == nil``` but still getting stack level too deep. Can you show in code how to fix?